# Laravel upload image field in Dashboard Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, json, laravel

[image: Network Debug]
[image]

I'm running the latest version of laravel using custom admin panel and i'm new to laravel development so this is kind of a newbie question, i'm trying to upload image in a form all other fields in the ads form is working fine except the image upload field it's giving me syntax Error even though i used the same code for posts form and it's working just fine

the form upload the image to upload folder then store it's id and url in database->media table and then put the same id in the ->ads table in the images column

here is the source code for the html form

```
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Name - English</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name_en" value="" class="form-control">
                    <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description - English</label>
                    <textarea class="wysiwyg-editor" name="description_en"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 margin-bottom-30">
                <label>Media - English</label>
                <div class="row lightbox photos margin-bottom-30 media_sort" data-link="https://****/admin/ads/6/mediasort" data-language="en">
                                        </div>
                <div class="form-group color-picker">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control " name="media_en[]" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.webm,.mp4" multiple>
                    <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Name - Spanish</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name_sp" value="" class="form-control">
                    <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description - Spanish</label>
                    <textarea class="wysiwyg-editor" name="description_sp"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 margin-bottom-30">
                <label>Media - Spanish</label>
                <div class="row lightbox photos margin-bottom-30 media_sort" data-link="https://*****/admin/ads/6/mediasort" data-language="sp">
                                        </div>
                <div class="form-group color-picker">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control " name="media_sp[]" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.webm,.mp4" multiple>
                    <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the adservice.php starting from line 81

```
        foreach ($active_languages as $language) {
        $ad->translate($language->code)->name = $request['name_' . $language->code] ? $request['name_' . $language->code] : $request['name_en'];
        $ad->translate($language->code)->description = $request['description_' . $language->code];
        $ad->translate($language->code)->excerpt = $request['excerpt_' . $language->code];

        $media_key = null;

        if ($request->hasFile('media_' . $language->code)) {
            $media_key = 'media_' . $language->code;
            }
        if ($media_key) {
            $media = $this->mediaService->upload($request, $media_key);
            if (count($media)) {
                $media_array = [];
                foreach ($media as $m) {
                    $m->authorable_type = \get_class(Auth::user());
                    $m->authorable_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $m->save();
                    $media_array[] = $m->id;
                }
                $old_images = (array) (\json_decode($ad->translate($language->code)->images, true));
                $media_array = \array_merge($old_images, $media_array);
                $ad->translate($language->code)->images = \json_encode($media_array);
            }
        } else {
            if (!empty($request['images_' . $language->code])) {
                $media_key = ('images_' . $language->code);
            }
            if ($media_key) {
                $ad->translate($language->code)->images = \json_encode(explode(',', $request[$media_key]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not about the blade. Check the request to see whether the image is included (The request params is in Chrome DevTools > Network > Select the Request > Headers > Scroll to bottom)

Comment: Add code excerpt from `app/Services/AdService.php` as the error occurred on that file on line 82 as per the screenshot

Comment: Sorry about that added adservice.php starting from line 81 and image for the DevTools > Network > Select the Request > Headers